# View html from archive using WebView

Tags: java, webview, javafx-2, javafx

I have zip-compressed file, which contains a set of html pages. I need to load html-pages from it. I need to redefine the mechanism of resolve of links. It is possible using WebView javafx?

Comment: What kind of archive? Where is it located relative to your application code? How do you deploy the application code and archive?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well your question. I'm guessing that you need to open html files.

I extracted the next code from [javafx 2 tutorial from Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm)

```
WebView browser = new WebView();
WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();
webEngine.load("http://mySite.com");
```

The load function takes a regular URL, so you can put a URL like

```
file:///C:/temp/test.html
```

and you will load an archive from your machine.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ZipFile` and `ZipEntry` to retrieve your html documents from the .zip file as an `InputStream`:

```
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("path to your .zip");
ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry("name of your html file");
InputStream is = zipFile.getInputStream(zipEntry); //InputStream to your file
```