# Jar file read property file from another project?

Tags: java, properties, backend

There are 2 projects A and B. Project A will be a jar file. Project B will include Proj A jar file. Here Project A needs to read property file from Project B when A is included in B. How can I achieve it. I googled lot and didnt find solution. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Is Project B a webapp? Where is the property file located in Project B? In the class path, or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

.jar files are comparable to .zip files (see [View html from archive using WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579816/view-html-from-archive-using-webview/38439913#38439913) ). Using this approach, you should be able to extract your .properties file as InputStream if you change `ZipFile` with `JarFile` and `ZipEntry` with `JarEntry`.